# scope for nested has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-many, belongs-to

I have a `has_many` relationship between two objects in Rails, let's say `A`, `B` and `C`

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :c
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  has_many :d
end

class D < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c
end
```

I want to obtain all the objects of class `D`, that has a specific `c` with belongs to an specific `B` and `A` . I could make the following `scope`s

```
  scope :by_c, ->(cc) { where(:c_id => cc) }

  scope :by_b, lambda { |bb|
    joins(:c).where('c.b_id = ?', bb)
  }
```

How should I do a `scope :by_a` ? Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :by_a ->(aa) {
  joins(:c).where(c_id: C.joins(:b).where(b_id: B.joins(:a).where(a_id: aa.id)))
}
```

Comment: I think that you have a mispell: It should be `scope: by_a -> (aa) { joins(:c).where(c_id: Polygon.joins(:b).where(b_id: B.joins(:a).where(:a_id => aa)))}` Please correct this to mark the answer as correct. Thanks for your help!